# Возможно ли вырезать встроенный в apk браузер?

Tags: android, браузер, apk

Может вопрос совсем наивный, ибо я совершенно не разбираюсь в программировании, но попытаю удачу: есть разобранный пакет apk приложения VK Me на андроид. Возможно ли что-то изменить/удалить в нём и собрать снова, чтобы в приложении никак не открывались внешние ссылки, а пользователя сразу бы перебрасывало в основной браузер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Распаковать и запаковать ты можешь через обычный архив, но подписать тебе придется уже своей подписью (в гугле читай о подписи APK)
Изменить без условно можешь, для начала выучи архитектуру приложения, на каком IDE она построена (на некоторых IDE файлы шифруются) Выясни на каком ЯП она написана (dart, kotlin, java, node) и после уже залезай в исходник, находи файл, который тебе нужен и начинай править